# Providing visibility to parent when child is visible

Tags: sharing

I have two custom `objects A and B`. `B(child)` has a lookup field to `A(parent)`. The `OWD` for `object A is private` and we employ certain sharing rules as per the requirements.

Is there any way such when a record of object B is made visible to some users, I need to make the parent record of object A also visible to them. The CRUD permissions on an object level are present for the users.

In terms of standard objects, it is similar to providing parent account record visibility to users who can see a child contact.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this using apex sharing. Created explicit share records of parent for the required users at the time of creation of the child record. Thus the parent was ensured to be visible to all those users for whom child was visible.

A custom apex sharing reason was created and the share records were created using this as the row cause. Thus, at the time of child deletion, it was possible to delete the share records created for this purpose only - i.e. the ones with the same row cause

Answer (score -1):

You can go for permission sets in this case. Create a new permission set with READ (Or whatever access you want to provide) access to object A. Assign this permission set to those users for whom you want this object to be visible.

Comment: The object is already visible. The OWD is private and now need to decide how to expose the relevant parent records to the user who can see the child records.